# How can I request permission to access gallery in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-permissions

I'm trying to develop an application that allows user to select photo from gallery to change profile picture, in kotlin compose. Of course, I need to access the gallery for this. I have looked on the internet for how to access gallery or choose image from gallery in compose

but I am confused because I come across this syntax

```
ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { uri: Uri? ->
        imageUri = uri
    }
```

from this documentation in medium :

https://ngengesenior.medium.com/pick-image-from-gallery-in-jetpack-compose-5fa0d0a8ddaf

and I come across this syntax

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
                if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
                    val permissions = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    requestPermissions(permissions, PERMISSION_CODE)
                } else{
                    chooseImageGallery();
                }
            }else{
                     chooseImageGallery();
            }
```

from this documentation :

https://medium.com/developer-student-clubs/android-kotlin-camera-using-gallery-ff8591c26c3e

I know one written in xml and the other with compose.

but as far as I know, accessing the gallery is a dangerous thing and we need to get the permission of the user, but according to my research, I have no idea how this **ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()** API does this automatically, so I don't have a popup asking the user for permission to access your gallery. do I need to watch? If I use the **ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()** API, will google play cause a problem? because we don't ask permission from user as it checks automatic permissions.

Please excuse me if I'm wrong, I don't know much about this subject and wanted to ask just to be sure.

There is a permission request syntax that I know in the project made with xml,
https://medium.com/developer-student-clubs/android-kotlin-camera-using-gallery-ff8591c26c3e

but I could not see a similar request syntax in the project made with compose.
https://ngengesenior.medium.com/pick-image-from-gallery-in-jetpack-compose-5fa0d0a8ddaf

Comment: `GetContent` does not require any runtime permissions, that's kind of the entire point of that API. Why are you trying to request any permissions at all?

Comment: I want to know if this poses a problem for google play because we are accessing user's gallery and it is a dangerous permission. Don't we need to get permission from the user? If there is no problem using GetContent, I can use it for google play. That's all I want to know.

Comment: You've never needed a dangerous permission if you are requesting the user to select exactly what image they want to give you access to. What made you think that was required?

Comment: @NewPartizal i had the same question 2 months ago in my project after some research i found that GetContent method doesn't need permission because it doesn't give access to gallery instead it gives you access only to the images the user selects not like the old way when you had to ask permission because you basically had to access the whole storage and then choose what you want

Comment: Thank you for both of your answers I understand clearly. it is acceptable